# Why is my name different on data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: bug, data-explorer, login, help

I joined [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/) associating with my existing credentials. It is showing a different name for me, like **jon.doe11943**

What is happening? Why is my name something different?

Comment: have you just created a account in the data site

Comment: Had logged into different SE sites, so it gave me option to associate data.stackexchange.com site with my account.

Comment: There's also a [FAQ section](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) on this now.